# What is the path that contains all Titanium Installed Modules in Mac?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I have a Mac with Mavericks and the last version of Titanium.

I have installed two modules and I need to modify a file in one module.

But I don't find the path.

Already searched in `/Library/Application Support/` but the Titanium Folder not exist (I tried to show hidden folders too, with no results).

Someone knows where are the modules?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Finder Click on the go to Folder and do the following steps

1)Type the following ~/library in text field

2)Click on Application Support

3)There you would find titanium and modules folder

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have encountered the path.

This is the path: /Users/YOURUSER/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules